# D3.js: Why the bar chart turns around if I add this two statements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Hey I had a barChart and I'm aware in svg the x=0 and y=0 is on the top-left corner so the graphics shows downwards. If I add a couple of statements it turns around.

```js
var w = 500;
var h = 100;
var barPadding = 1;

var dataset = [5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 25, 34, 54, 64, 32, 11, 32, 42, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var rectangles = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / dataset.length);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - d;
  })
  .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d * 4;
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
  });
```

```html
<script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

I have two questions, 
a)why on the examples they use h-d for the y positioning?
If the svg height is 100 for example and a number on the dataset is 60, shouldn't that position the bar on the y=40 from the top left corner? Yet that is not the case when I render this, the bar shows on the same y position for all the bars

Why is it rendering the bars correctly with those given values? What makes the bar "grow from the bottom" in this case, cause if I do the math it makes me expect a different thing.

Comment: The `y` position of an svg rect is the **top** of the rect.  The bottom is `y + height`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, the reason why the y values are cut off at the correct place is because the svg has a height of 100.  But if you carefully inspect the svg, every rectangle extends beyond the bottom of the svg, they are just not visible since there is no overflow.

h-d is correct for the starting y position, if a value was 60, then (100-60) would equal 40 as you have correctly stated.  However, the actual height should be just d rather than d * 4.  I do not know where the d * 4 came from.

So if your value is 60, then y would be 40, height would be 60 which would extend to the bottom of the svg.

Hope this helps.